# Strange geospatial plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, geojson

I'm trying to plot Spain with each country, so I'm using a `.geojson` from github.
My code is the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(geojsonio)
spdf <- geojson_read("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/spain-provinces.geojson",  what = "sp")

library(broom)
spdf_fortified <- tidy(spdf, region = "cod_prov")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = spdf_fortified, aes( x = long, y = lat, group = id), fill="white", color="grey") +
  theme_void() +
  coord_map()
```

And the output is really erratic, the polygons are really messed.

[image]

Hi have some questions regarding it.
First of all, why this behaviour?

Also reading some tutorials I found that we need to "fortify" the spdf, why's that?

And finally, what does `group` is doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to do any data processing steps, if you just directly read the GeoJSON in using the `{sf}` package, which is also well-integrated to `{ggplot2}` graphics.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.7.2, GDAL 2.4.2, PROJ 5.2.0
library(ggplot2)

spain <- read_sf("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/spain-provinces.geojson") 

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = spain)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>